# How to get value from input with value that has been set as part of ngOnInit()? - Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have set a form's input field value in my component.ts file, however when I try to post the data using an API, the FormData is returning undefined rather than the value. I have checked this when not using setValue() for the input field, and the data is sent okay.

Component.ts:

```
this.commentForm.controls['createdBy'].setValue(sessionStorage['name']);
this.commentForm.controls['createdBy'].disable();
```

onSubmit() function:

```
onSubmit() {
        this.webService.postClubComment(this.commentForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
                                                                this.commentForm.reset();
                                                                window.location.reload();
        });
    }
```

postClubComment():

```
postClubComment(comment: any) {
        let postData = new FormData();
        postData.append("createdBy", comment.createdBy);
        postData.append("comment", comment.comment);

        let today = new Date();
        let todayDate = today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();
        postData.append("date", todayDate)

        return this.http.post(this.URL + this.clubId + "/comments", postData);
    }
```

Data is being posted successfully, however the createdBy field is being posted as `undefined`

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: You need to use `this.commentForm.getRawValues()` to include controls that are disabled

Comment: Thanks, apologies for asking such a stupid question, thought it was due to the value being set and no value being entered rather than the input being disabled :)

Comment: No worries. We've all been there :)